# Update parameters of a function in a while loop

Tags: while-loop, gdal

I am trying to execute a while loop that holds a function with parameters. However, I have noticed that the parameters inside the while loop are not updated which leads to an infinite while loop. Is there a reason behind the fact that the function parameters are not being updated after every loop?

```
import shapefile
from osgeo import gdal
#import rasterio

print (gdal.VersionInfo())
def pointInRect(x, y, x1, y1, w, h): # check if a raster point is in another raster
    x2, y2 = x1+w, y1+h
    if (x1 < x and x < x2):
        if (y1 < y and y < y2):
            return True
    return False

# Open the shapes centroids
shp_cntrds = 'Path to centroids'
sf_cntrds = shapefile.Reader(shp_cntrds)
shapes_cntrds = sf_cntrds.shapes()
records_cntrds = sf_cntrds.records()

# adjust labels position according to its shapes centroids position
for i in range(len(records_cntrds)):
    print(i)

    tods = gdal.Open(str(records_cntrds[i][1]))

    width = tods.RasterXSize
    height = tods.RasterYSize

    tods.SetGeoTransform([shapes_cntrds[i].points[0][0] - (width * 0.005), 0.01, 0,
                          shapes_cntrds[i].points[0][1] + (height * 0.005), 0, -0.01])

    gt = tods.GetGeoTransform()
    left = gt[0]
    bottom = gt[3] + width * gt[4] + height * gt[5]
    right = gt[0] + width * gt[1] + height * gt[2]
    top = gt[3]
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.SetUTM(32, 1)  # set crs
    srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS('WGS84')  # set crs
    tods.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())  # set Projection and save file
    print(width, height)
    tods = None

# iterate through Labels and move labels away from each others  if they overlapp
for i in range(len(records_cntrds)):
    tods1 = gdal.Open(str(records_cntrds[i][1])) # records of the centroid shapefile contains the raster file path



    width = tods1.RasterXSize
    height = tods1.RasterYSize
    gt = tods1.GetGeoTransform()
    left = gt[0]
    bottom = gt[3] + width * gt[4] + height * gt[5]
    right = gt[0] + width * gt[1] + height * gt[2]
    top = gt[3]
    face = [x for x in list(range(len(records_cntrds))) if x != i]
    tods1 = None
    for j in face:
        if str(records_cntrds[i][1]) == str(records_cntrds[j][1]):
            pass
        else:

            ds_raster_face = gdal.Open(str(records_cntrds[j][1]))
            #print(str(records_cntrds[i][1]))
            #print(str(records_cntrds[j][1]))
            gt_face = ds_raster_face.GetGeoTransform()
            width_face = ds_raster_face.RasterXSize
            height_face = ds_raster_face.RasterYSize
            left_face = gt_face[0]
            bottom_face = gt_face[3] + width_face * gt_face[4] + height_face * gt_face[5]
            right_face = gt_face[0] + width_face * gt_face[1] + height_face * gt_face[2]
            top_face = gt_face[3]

            width1 = width
            left1 = left
            height1 = height
            bottom1 = bottom
            while pointInRect(left_face, bottom_face, left1, bottom1, width1*0.01, height1*0.01) :
                tods2 = gdal.Open(str(records_cntrds[i][1]))
                gt = tods2.GetGeoTransform()
                width1 = tods2.RasterXSize
                height1 = tods2.RasterYSize
                left1 = gt[0]
                bottom1 = gt[3] + width1 * gt[4] + height1 * gt[5]
                print("while executed")
                tods2.SetGeoTransform([(shapes_cntrds[i].points[0][0] - (width1 * 0.005)) - 2.7, 0.01, 0,
                                  (shapes_cntrds[i].points[0][1] + (height1 * 0.005)) - 2.8, 0, -0.01])
                print("coordinates changed to",(i, left1, bottom1, width1, height1))
                tods2 = None
```

The while loop should break when the function return false but it is repeating the same thing. Are the gt values not updatet or are they initialized again ?

Comment: all your calculations inside the loop are based on `tods2` which is `tods2 = gdal.Open(str(records_cntrds[i][1]))` As I don't see any update to `i` you are always reading the same data, thus always get the same values ...

Comment: i is actually related to the for loop because I want to compare all raster data I have and see if they overlap with each others

Comment: Still, you never update `i` in the `while` loop, thus you are always operating on the very same data ...